# Wordpress no carga archivo .php dentro de iframe

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

Tengo un archivo .php que incluye contenido HTML en mi ftp del hosting, el cual quiero insertar a modo de iframe dentro de una página de wordpress.

Si hago esto con un archivo HTML puro, siempre funciona a la hora de insertarlo:

```
<iframe
  src="https://www.mipagina.com/wp-content/themes/mitema/assets/micarpeta/miarchivo1.html"
  frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
  width="(ancho)" height="(alto)"></iframe>
```

Si de lo contrario hago esto con el archivo PHP, no me aparece el iframe:

```
<iframe
  src="https://www.mipagina.com/wp-content/themes/mitema/assets/micarpeta/miarchivo2.php"
  frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
  width="(ancho)" height="(alto)"></iframe>
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea a qué se puede deber o cómo resolverlo?

Muchas gracias de antemano. :)

Comment: ¿Aparece algún error en consola? ¿Y qué contiene tu archivo `miarchivo2.php`?

Comment: Hola @Lixus, no aparece ningún error de consola y mi archivo simplemente contiene una mezcla entre PHP y HTML, por lo cual lo he exportado como .php - lo he probado en XAMPP localmente y funciona todo bien. He probado también entretanto a insertar algo de PHP tan simple como un `echo` entre tags de `<?php` `?>` directamente en la página de Wordpress y no lo procesa. ¿Parece como si Wordpress no ejecutase el PHP así sin más - quizás por motivos de seguridad? Habrá que instalar algún plugin primero?

Comment: Checa si el motor de PHP está activo en tu entorno de Wordpress

Comment: Me sale en mi página del hosting que está habilitada la versión PHP 7.0 en mi dominio así que supongo que afirmativo.

Comment: El único error similar que he visto es cuando intentas cargar un iframe con protocolo HTTPS como es tu caso, y el sitio donde lo cargas es HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Debe haber algún problema o con la ruta del archivo o con la forma en que estás intentando presentarlo.

He hecho varias pruebas de la siguiente manera y **todas funcionan**:

En el archivo que se abre a través de la URL:

---

### (a). pruebas desde los archivos vía SFTP:

**PRUEBA 1a:**

**archivo.php**

```
$iframe='<iframe src="ruta/carpeta/valida/mi-iframe.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="(ancho)" height="(alto)"></iframe>'; 
echo $iframe;
```

*Resultado*: funciona. Muestra en iframe todo el contenido del archivo `mi-iframe.php`

**PRUEBA 2a:**

**archivo.php**

```
$iframe='<iframe src="http://mi-sitio.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="(ancho)" height="(alto)"></iframe>'; 
echo $iframe;
```

*Resultado*: funciona. Muestra en iframe la página inicial de mi sitio.

### ---

### (b). pruebas desde Wordpress directamente:

**PRUEBA 1b:**

**nuevo post de wp**

```
<iframe src="http://www.mi-sitio.com/ruta/carpeta/valida/mi-iframe.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="(ancho)" height="(alto)"></iframe>
```

*Resultado*: funciona. Muestra en iframe todo el contenido del archivo `mi-iframe.php`

**PRUEBA 2b:**

**nuevo post de wp**

```
<iframe src="http://mi-sitio.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="(ancho)" height="(alto)"></iframe>
```

*Resultado*: funciona. Muestra en iframe la página inicial de mi sitio.

---

### (c). prueba con [Embeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds)

Wordpress da la posibilidad de embeber contenido multimedia de esta manera.

```
[embed width="123" height="456"]https://youtu.be/LMchhs_REzg[/embed]
```

*Resultado:* Como mi contenido no era multimedia, probé con un vídeo de Youtube, y funciona.